# MeteorJS selector between html and events

Tags: jquery, meteor

I'm a beginner learning MeteorJS, and this question is with reference to this particular step in the tutorial
http://meteortips.com/second-meteor-tutorial/managing-todos/

In the input tag of the html file, I used `name="todoItem`. In the corresponding events block of the JS file, I used jQuery to capture the event with `keyup [name="todoItem"]`.

Why is it then when I change the name in the html input tag to say, `name="x"`, and do the same with `keyup [name="x"]`, it doesn't seem to work?

Am I missing something with my understanding of how the selectors are working in this scenario?

```js
    Template.todoItem.events({
      'click .delete-todo': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var docId = this._id;

        var confirm = window.confirm("Delete this task?");
        if (confirm) {
          Todos.remove({
            _id: docId
          });
        }
      },
      'keyup [name="todoItem"]': function(e) {
        var docId = this._id;
        var t = $(e.target).val();
        Todos.update({
          _id: docId
        }, {
          $set: {
            name: t
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

```html
<template name="todoItem">
  <li>
    <input type="text" value="{{name}}" name="todoItem">[
    <a href="#" class="delete-todo">Delete</a>]
  </li>
</template>
```

Comment: https://www.codementor.io/tips/7473712871/a-better-way-to-attach-event-listeners-in-meteor
I followed this tutorial, and changed 'name' to 'data-action' attribute instead in both the html and event listener and now it works. Still don't get it why it didn't work in the first place when I changed in 'name' though

Comment: `keyup input[name="todoItem"]` you had a wrong selector, you can test `$('input[name="todoItem"]')[0]` in the console if it finds the input or not.